# How to correctly use rotating frames in Schrodinger equation for Jaynes-Cummings Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, schroedinger-equation, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-optics

Jaynes-Cummings Hamiltonian describes the system of an atom interacting with light.

$$\hat{H}=\hbar\omega_{light}\left(\hat{n}+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\hbar\dfrac{\omega_{atom}}{2}\left(|e\rangle \langle e|-|g\rangle \langle g|\right)+\hbar\dfrac{\Omega_{Rabi}}{2}\left(\hat{a}^{\dagger}|g\rangle\langle e|+\hat{a}|e\rangle\langle g|\right)$$

The question is whether this Hamiltonian would be equivalent to the one where I set

$$\omega_{light}\rightarrow 0,$$

$$\omega_{atom}\rightarrow \omega_{atom}-\omega_{light}$$

and keeping $\Omega_{Rabi}$ the same?

The motivation is that I want to go into the frame co-rotating with the photons so I don't get the quickly evolving phase from the light in the Schrodinger evolution.

Comment: What you need is a time dependant unitary transformation, namely the rotation $R(t)= \exp( -i\omega_{at}} t S_z/\hbar)$. Such a transformation modifys the Hamiltonian, adding a term looking like $-\omega_{at} S_z$.

Comment: About my own comment: read \omega_{light} where I wrote \omega_{at}. And anyways \Omega_Rabi depend only on the energy or frequency difference, not absolutes values.